# Snowflake - timezone conversion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date column in snowflake which actually shows different timezones GMT, GMT+2, GMT-4 etc. And the column in Varchar datatype. How do I convert these to a common GMT time zone in a query output?

Sample values like:

| DATE |
| --- |
| 1/22/2024 9:51:44 AM GMT+2 |
| 1/23/2024 3:01:16 PM GMT |
| 1/23/2024 4:11:56 PM GMT-4 |

Comment: `How do I convert these to a common GMT time zone?`  you may want to provide information on what you are doing.  Simple query, UDF, Stored Procedure as this will have an impact on what is suggested.   So without all that, what not just pull out the date/time and then add the hours from the GMT to it?

Comment: Just wanted to convert to a common GMT time zone in query itself. Do not want to use Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you haven't provided all the details to your question that are needed, but I made some assumptions.  The first of which is that every string value in your Snowflake column contains the basic format that you've provided and that they ALL make reference to `GMT`.

I was not clear as to what you wanted the output to be, so I provided a few options that are all essentially the same thing.

First, I create a CTE to imitate your values:

```
with x as (
    select date_field
    from (values ('1/22/2024 9:51:44 AM GMT+2'),('1/23/2024 3:01:16 PM GMT'),('1/23/2024 4:11:56 PM GMT-4') x (date_field))
)
```

Second, you have a tiny issue with your GMT reference that has no +/- offset.  So, I create a case statement to rectify that so every string has the same pattern.

```
case when split_part(date_field,'GMT',2) = '' then date_field||'+0' else date_field end as date_string
```

Last, I convert the string to a timestamp using standard Snowflake notation.  The final query everything in it is below.

```
with x as (
select date_field
from (values ('1/22/2024 9:51:44 AM GMT+2'),('1/23/2024 3:01:16 PM GMT'),('1/23/2024 4:11:56 PM GMT-4') x (date_field))
)
select 
     case when split_part(date_field,'GMT',2) = '' then date_field||'+0' else date_field end as date_string
    ,to_timestamp_ltz(date_string,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM GMTTZH') gmt_to_local
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(date_string,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM GMTTZH') gmt_only
    ,to_timestamp_tz(date_string,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM GMTTZH') offset_to_gmt
from x;
```

Comment: Tried this in my query. but I am getting Can't parse ' 1/16/2024, 4:13:21 PM GMT+2' as timestamp with format 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM GMTTZH'

Comment: Do you really have a comma in the value string?  In order for this to work, your strings need to be consistently formatted at a minimum.  You could replace the comma with a blank to handle it in your case statement, though, if needed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But yes there is a comma in the value string. I replaced and your solution worked. Thank you much.